# "XML Parsing Error: no root element found"

Tags: javascript, php

I'm testing some code to be able to upload mp3-files and have them stored on the website.
I've followed some tutorials on how to do this with JS and PHP, but I always get the error (in firefox):

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://filesavetest.jasperdg.repl.co/ajaxfile.php
Line Number 29, Column 3:
```

Can someone help me?

Here's my HTML:

```js
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSFileSaveTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div >
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  <input type="button" id="btn_uploadfile" 
     value="Upload" 
     onclick="uploadFile();" >
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadFile(){
        var files = document.getElementById("file").files;
        if(files.length>0){
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("file", files[0])
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //Set POST method and ajax file path
            xhttp.open("POST", "ajaxfile.php", true)
            //Call on request changes state
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    var response = this.responseText;
                    if(response==1){
                        alert("upload suc6")
                    }else{
                        alert("file not uploaded")
                    }
                }
            }
            //Send request with data
            xhttp.send(formdata)
            
        }else{
            alert("Please select a file")
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my PHP:

```php
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
   //Filename
   $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   //Upload location
   $dir = "upload/";
   //File path
   $path = $dir.$filename;
   //File extension
   $file_extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);
   //Valid extensions
   $valid_ext = array("mp3");

   $response = 0;

   //Check extension
   if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_ext)){
      //Upload file
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)){
         $response=1;
      }
   }
   echo $response;
   exit;
}

?>
```

And here's my file structure:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Tnx!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD3Om.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server doesn't provide a Content-Type header, XMLHttpRequest **assumes that the MIME type is "text/xml"**. You can avoid this by calling overrideMimeType() to specify a different type.

Don't know exactly but it seems to me that the correct mime type for MP3 is audio/mpeg or application/octet-stream.

Try to set mimeType before xhttp.open, with:

```
xhttp.overrideMimeType("audio/mpeg");
```

Or

```
xhttp.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
```