# Uploading using PHP an JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to add a file upload function to my website using Javascript and PHP and have followed some tutorials and asked [a question on this topic earlier for the MIMEType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504059/xml-parsing-error-no-root-element-found), but now that issue is solved, I still can't upload any files and like you can see in the code get alerted by "file not uploaded", can someone help?

my HTML:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>JSFileSaveTest</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
  <input type="button" id="btn_uploadfile" 
     value="Upload" 
     onclick="uploadFile();" >
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadFile(){
        var files = document.getElementById("file").files;
        if(files.length>0){
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("file", files[0])
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //Set POST method and ajax file path
            xhttp.overrideMimeType("audio/mpeg");
            xhttp.open("POST", "ajaxfile.php", true)
            //Call on request changes state
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                    var response = this.responseText;
                    if(response==1){
                        alert("upload suc6")
                    }
                                        else{
                        alert("file not uploaded")
                                        }
                                }
            }
            //Send request with data
            xhttp.send(formdata)
            
        }else{
            alert("Please select a file")
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my PHP:

```php
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
   //Filename
   $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   //Upload location
   $dir = "upload/";
   //File path
   $path = $dir.$filename;
   //File extension
   $file_extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);
   //Valid extensions
   $valid_ext = array("mp3", "mp4", "jpg", "png", "txt");

   $response = 0;

   //Check extension
   if(in_array($file_extension, $valid_ext)){
      //Upload file
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path)){
         $response=1;
      }
   }
    
   echo $response;
   exit;
}

?>
```

Tnx!

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php. Try to get the warning text